# iPhone CSS viewport issue - website "wobbles" left/right

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

On iPhone (and only iPhone, not Android), the mobile version of our website displays fine, but when the user tries to swipe left/right (on a slider or gallery, for example), the entire site "wobbles" left/right, then goes back to the right place.

In other words, it's NOT clipped or overflowing the screen, it's sized perfectly, but it "sorta" scrolls left/right and it *shouldn't*.

I'm sure it has something to do with container or viewport sizing, but don't know enough to fix the problem myself.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Add this meta tag to your header

```
< meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" >
```

also make sure your html css includes these

```
html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow-x: hidden;    
    overflow-y: visible;
    max-width: 100% ;
    display: flex;
   

}
```

this will do it . tried all solution, also by trying you can see where you are having some elements overflowing to the right or left.
in my case I had a carousel padding of 20px, to the edge of screen on desktop, but mobile was wobbleing left and right..

this will help you identify where the overflow is happening, great suggestion above, thank you for that..

```
* {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your outermost container probably body:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

To see what is causing the overflow, you can try to add an outline around everything and it will allow you to easily see what is messing with it:

```
* {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it doesn't sound like body overflow is the problem, I would still try addressing it just to see what happens. I would do something like this:

CSS

```
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

At least this will help you diagnose the problem, even if it doesn't work.

Hope this helps!